# SQL count(*) statement returning 0 whilst table contains several hundred rows

Tags: sql, database, intersystems-cache

I am running queries on an Intersystems Cache database via an ODBC connection. It had been working perfectly up until a couple of hours ago when sending a statement like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cmr_table` started to return 0. The statement `SELECT * FROM cmr_table` returns plenty of rows and seems to work as normal.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you do anything _a couple of hours ago_?

Comment: Just querying the DB, nothing more than that

Comment: are you still have a problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, you added new index. Try to rebuild all indices in your class.

```
do ##class(your.class).%BuildIndices()
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer - please could you explain further?

Comment: Such behavior possible, when SQL optimizer used indices, which was not not built yet. Can you try to execute your query in System Management Portal ? And there you can see query plan, which could help to understand, which index, it uses.